.NET MAUI Uranium 2.9.1 PickerField Bug on Windows
When I click on the PickerField for Uranium for the first time, all the options appear, occupying the entire Field However, when I click a second time, the selection area decreases in size, and I can only select an option if I click very close to the label. I want the Picker to consistently occupy the entire field.
My project repository
first attempt
other attempts
xml code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:uranium="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui"
             x:Class="MyUraniumProject.MainPage"
             Shell.NavBarHasShadow="True"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
             >


        <StackLayout Margin="20">
 

        <material:PickerField HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/>
        <material:PickerField HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/>


    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>

code behind
namespace MyUraniumProject
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List = new ObservableCollection<string>() { 
            "a", "b", "c", "d"
            };

            BindingContext = this;
        }

    
    }

}

Uranium repository:https://github.com/enisn/UraniumUI
Uranium documentation: https://enisn-projects.io/docs/en/uranium/latest/Getting-Started

which behavior do you feel is the "correct" one?  If your question has to do with some third party library, please include a link to the project repo or homepage.  Do not assume everyone will know what you're referring to.

Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am referring to the library https://github.com/enisn/UraniumUI, and the expected behavior is depicted in the first photo, where the picker covers the entire field.
